# When I use preview mode in google tag manger it opens a new tab for a beta version of tag assistant, how do I get rid of that?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Tag manager is acting weird whenever I use preview mode.
It opens up a new tab called tag assistant and then it asks me for the link.

Before it would appear below in the site, but now it covers the entire page and it opens a new page. How do I get back to the old loved version when the debugger showed below?

[image]

Comment: I added an image but I was dumb enough that I forgo to write a description

Answer (score 2):

You don't, apparently (get the old one back, I mean). This is the new debug/preview mode that seems to be here to stay. To be fair, it comes with a [number of new features](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/new-preview-mode-google-tag-manager/) (no longer dependent on third party cookies, follows interactions across pages etc).

These seemed to be geared towards developer types rather than casual users, so the new features might not make up for the changed user experience (for starters, you need a multiple monitor arrangement for this to make sense), but as far as I can tell this is just something you have to live with.

Comment: I am having huge issues with it not actually going into preview with tags behaving strangely, plus I HATE it and I am a developer lol.

Comment: @Bibberty, I know what you mean. We're in the middle of a big rollout for a large-ish site, and this morning I had ten frontend developers chew my head off for something I am completely innocent of. I guess we all get used to it, but it's a different change to like when it comes without warning.

Comment: I know, thanks for your comment though, I read Simo Ahava post. I posted this when they made the change and I thought I was in a beta program, but now I know it is a general thing. Google should have told us about this change to be prepared

Answer (score 0):

Once you click the preview it will open an new window/page, and all your helper tools to check pixels are missing.

Workaround Solution: Just copy the newly opened URL
with the parameter "?gtm_debug=1709535815597"
and paste it to a new tab you like, where your tools are present.
Then close the preview new window which GTM has opened, and work on the new tab where you've pasted the new link.